# Including Area name in claims authroization Resource identifier

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif

I am attempting to create an `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` implementation which seems pretty straight forward. However, due to the fact that my MVC application utilizes Areas, the Resource property of the `AuthorizationContext` object (received as an argument of the `CheckAccess` method) isn't providing enough information about my resource.

I'm looking for some way to indicate a Resource description at the Controller or Area level without having to decorate every action method. I attempted to add `[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Resource = "MyResourceName")]` to a controller but that resulted in an exception due to the lack of `Operation` value. I was hoping to achieve a hierarchical cascading setting. For example, all ActionMethods would use the resource defined in the attribute and would resort to the default operation identity mechanism.

Is there a something I'm missing here? Is there a framework or Thinktecture.IdentityModel helper utility for accomplishing this? Is there an opportunity to register a custom AuthorizationContent generator class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in mechanism is a little low level for doing these sorts of check (since it's based on CAS). You should look into the Thinktecture IdentityModel helper library for these things. We provide an easier mechanism/API to do claims based checks:

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/26/using-claims-based-authorization-in-mvc-and-web-api/

Comment: Thanks for the response, Brock. I did find that post in my initial research. I also pulled in Thinktecture.IdentityModel 3.6.1. and registered the ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute as a global filter. From what I can tell, however, this doesn't include any information about the area in the claim. Is the recommendation to define method-level `ClaimAuthorize` decorations? Is there any way to override the `Resource` value of the `AuthorizationContext`?

Comment: Check that, I see that you can decorate the controller and then add more granular authorization attributes to action methods as needed. ClaimsAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess does seem to be called once for each `ClaimsAuthroize` instance: the global filter, the controller and the action, in this case. It does appear that Thinktecture.IdentityModel allows me to implement claims within areas with minimal configuration. What would have been nice is an area specific resource identifier template or something of the sort. Just sayin' ;)